# Why does this character want to kill Anton specifically?

Tags: character-motivation, night-watch-cycle, last-watch

**This question contains spoilers of the Final watch (and previous books)!**

In the Final watch (or Last watch) novel by Sergei Lukyanenko, the vampire

> Gennadiy Saushkin

wants to kill Anton because he blames him for

> death of his son Kostya

but at the same time, the vampire cooperates with the Inquisitor Edgar, who is equally to be blamed for it. After all, they chased Kostya alongside with Anton in the previous book.

Also, Anton didn't even kill Kostya, it was a suicide or rather an unfortunate accident, as we know [from this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/39174/66567). Edgar mentioned several times, that the vampire wants to kill Anton after their task in Scotland is done.

**Why does the vampire want Anton's death so desperately? And why doesn't he hate Edgar equally?**

Comment: Feel free to edit the spoiler tags, I was unsure how to do it without having the question all hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply enough, Gennady isn't being entirely reasonable about the situation, but there's more to it than that.

First of all, we don't know if Gennady is aware of what exactly happened at the launch centre. It may as well be the case that he thinks Anton was the one who pushed Kostya to drop out of university, become entangled with the Day Watch and all that nonsense, and then killed him for some reasons unknown. Even if he does know the truth (Anton didn't visit Gennady after his son's death), maybe he doesn't care?

Kostya was his only son, and Gennady clearly loved him very much. More than that, he loved his wife... and she ended her life of grief when Kostya died. So, as far as Gennady is concerned, Anton is one person who is somehow clearly connected to the deaths of the two people in his life he cared about and loved.

Finally, his intentions aren't motivated only by hate: he wants to have revenge on Anton, that's true. But I'd argue that more  than that, he wants to be reunited with his family, and that's the main reason he joins the Final Watch. Anton even remarks on the plane to Edinburgh that at that moment revenge is a secondary concern for Gennady.

Comment: it's worth to point that Anton was the person sent to stop Kostya and the last person who seen him alive - it is not a huge leap of logic here in blaming Anton for his death: he COULD have stop Kostya but he didn't,

Comment: That is true as well. Everything points to Anton as the culprit, and, to be fair, he kind of is

Comment: @Gallifreyan Thanks for the answer! I have two items to solve:   

1. Why didn't Anton tell him anything? They were travelling together for several hours, but Anton didn't even try (it kind of looks like he agrees with Gennady).   
2. I am also not sure about the reunion motivation. Again, why Anton? That actually is the point of another of my questions: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201571/why-should-anton-be-useful-to-the-final-watch-in-this-action

Comment: @TGar regarding your first point: Anton likely felt guilty after the accident to go to Gennady and explain himself. After that the former likely didn't make any social appearances as he was busy powering up and with the Final Watch business. And after the kerfuffle began, it was way past the point of apologies. As for your second question, I'll try to answer it

Comment: It sure was past the point of apologies, but it didn't have to be past the point of explaining what happened. Anton could save his life by explanation. But @Yasskier has a point here that Gennady would maybe still blame Anton because he could have stop Kostya (I didn't noticed the comment before).